# Reading Russian characters in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to read excel file using PHPExcel which contains russian characters. But I am getting `??????` in place of string. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');
$data->read('samplefile.xls');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++)
    {
        echo "\"".utf8_decode($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])."\",";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: You claim to be using PHPExcel, but this code is using Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader

Comment: sorry when i didn't noticed the name